# gitlab merge request. Who is the assignee?

Tags: gitlab

There is one particular point I don't understand for GitLab's merge requests.

I cloned a repository and made a feature branch. I worked something on it, committed it, and pushed the new branch to my GitLab repo.

With that I can make a merge request. When I do it says:

Assignee (and Assign to me)

Who should I assign it to? I mean, if I assign it to me, it is going to be me who "reviews" the change and approves it, so what is the point?

Or should I assign it to the repository administrator? Or to other member reviewers, so that they can check that and approve the merge?

What is the "Assign to me" option, and how does that makes sense?

Answer (score 10):

There is [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#assign-a-user-to-a-merge-request) for that. It states:

> This person owns the merge request, but isn’t responsible for reviewing it.

Additionally, the documentation explains an exemplary [merge request workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#merge-request-workflows):

1. You would typically create the MR **before** working on your feature branch.
2. Then you can use the `Assign to me` feature to indicate that you are the one currently working on implementing the features of the MR.
3. After your work is done you can [request a review](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#request-a-review) following [these guidelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#review-a-merge-request).
4. After [finishing the review](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#submit-a-review) you can fall back to step 8 in the [MR workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#merge-request-workflows).

Comment: Oh, you are talking about the WIP right? where you work on the feature branch before requesting to merge it

Comment: "After your work is done you can request approval from a reviewer by assigning the MR"

Then why does gitlab have a "Reviewer" Field in the merge request form?

Also as I read this correctly, your statement disagrees with the other answer? Where the other answer says the field should not be used for reviewers?

Comment: @ChefLax I have rewritten my answer and added additional documentation based explanation to hopefully clear up some of the points. Yes you are right the assignee and the reviewer should not be the same person, I had that wrong in my earlier revision.

Answer (score 3):

What I have experienced in practice and also what can be seen when reading through the other answers to this question is that while there might be a predefined idea from gitlab on how to use this field, many teams use this feature differently. It is best to ask your team/company how they use this field.

What I have seen when working is this workflow:

1. you create a MR, you assign the reviewer as asignee
2. now he reviewed, he assigns you as the asignee
3. then you handle his review comments and then assign him as assignee again, since he should now take a final look at the MR and possibly approve it

Answer (score 2):

The people who are assigned to a merge request are the people who are responsible for it, not in a review kind of sense.
Usually it is the person who creates the pull request who counts as responsible for it i.e. has the responsibility of merging when all reviewers are happy and have approved or making changes according to the reviewers comments.

However, multiple people can have this responsibility as it is not always prudent for this to rest on a single person (what if the person goes on vacation?).
Another case is if multiple developers have been working on the same feature and therefor have shared responsibility for the code in the merge request.

It is actually described in [Gitlabs Documentation for Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/index.html#assign-multiple-users)

TL;DR Multiple people can have responsibility / can be accountable for the merge request.